# how to use database Synchronization available in XAMPP

Tags: database, synchronization, xampp

I have two instance of XAMPP running, one on my laptop for development and other on the remote machine for testing.
Both the system has Windows 7 professional installed.
XAMPP version on my laptop is 1.77 
XAMPP version on remote machine is 1.74 
I am trying the Synchronize the two databases, but dont know how to do it. Synchronize tab in the phpMyAdmin also doesnt have much information.
If anyone has done that, can you please guide me through. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for development purposes and your database have less that few gigabytes you can use [Dropbox](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2F&ei=ldI8T8yCLIuWhQfxmPHJBQ&usg=AFQjCNGLRmWLy_c8ebbz09BgsukcLpmnwQ) or other network drive. See the guide:

http://kav.in/complete-guide-on-syncing-xampp-and-mamp-using-dropbox

Comment: dropbox is good for file sync but not for database. Its mentioned on top of the page(http://kav.in/complete-guide-on-syncing-xampp-and-mamp-using-dropbox) as one of the disadvantages of dropbox. What I am looking for is a one way shifting of data from one database to another.

Comment: So why won'u use phpmyadmin's import/export to dump the db as sql and then load it?

Comment: I have been using that since a long time, but now the database dump size has crossed 170MB and will carry on to increase, so i was wondering if there is a better way to sync the data so only the new changes are fed in the system and not the complete database.